# Need help dealing with a Fatal Exception caused by java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

So, I ran into this error just yesterday in Android Studio that I've never seen before, caused by a piece of code that hasn't been touched over the past 3 months. This came from the code being used to register for push notifications and was working fine earlier this week, but now it results in this error:

```
05-20 10:37:02.064 22471-22681/com.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RegIntentService]
                                                               Process: com.appname, PID: 22471
                                                               java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzeb(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.appname.services.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:32)
                                                                   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Here is my RegistrationIntentService class:

```
package com.appname.services;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;
import com.appname.MainSharedPreferences;
import com.appname.R;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }
    public static void startService(final Context context) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        context.startService(intent); //HERE is the line that is causing the crash
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        try {
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId) , GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            MainSharedPreferences.saveGCMInstanceToken(token, getApplicationContext());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the line of code that is calling the above class from my MainActivity class:

```
RegistrationIntentService.startService(getApplicationContext());
```

Some info on my MainActivity if it helps...

```
public class MainActivity extends SocialActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener

public abstract class SocialActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback
```

I've tried jumping back to several older commits, but got the same error. This led me to believe that maybe there was problem with my Android Studio or java version. I updated my java version and reinstalled Android Studio, still the same error. Also tried on a separate computer with older versions, still the same error.

I even tried migrating from GCM to Firebase according to [this guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) and ended up getting the same error again.

I can comment out the line that crashes the app and it will run fine, but then I no longer receive notifications.

Any help or advice on this matter would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** Here are my relevant compile/classpath statements as well...

In the appname build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

In the app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    //...
}

allprojects {
    //...
}

android {
   //...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0"
    //...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**update may 27:**

we just released an update (`version 9.0.1`) to fix the incompatibility I mentioned in my first edit.
Please update your dependencies and let us know if this is still an issue.

*Thanks!*

---

**original answer May 20:**

The issue you are experiencing is due to an incompatibility between
`play-services / firebase sdk v9.0.0` and 
`com.android.support:appcompat-v7 >= 24`
(the version released with android-N sdk)

You should be able to fix it by targeting an earlier version of the support library. Like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

Comment: This matches what I already had when the error happened. I've edited the original post to show my library versions at the bottom.
This error also happened when I was using 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0' with 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0' which really doesn't seem to make sense...

Comment: I imagine that some other dependency is pulling in appcompat-v7:24 :(

Comment: Not working for me either. I checked androidDependencies task for it and there are only two mentions both saying version :23.4.0

Comment: Do you have any example project where I can reproduce it? So far I could reproduce it by adding the appcompat-v7:24 lib and I fix that by downgrading to :23.  (PS: we are working on a fix on the root problem, updates soon)

Comment: and the fix is out! please try version 9.0.1 which should fix this

Comment: Updating my dependency to compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1" got rid of that error. Thank you!