# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError in gcm push notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Previously, GCM was working fine but after updating Google Play Services it stopped working. I am encountered with the following logcat error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Con‌​text)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in /data/app/com.notnul.notnul-1/base.apk) at com.notnul.notnul.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentSer‌​vice.java:53)
```

And here is my code where logcat is pointing:

```
instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
GCM_Token = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getToken(authorizedEntity, scope);
GCM_InstaceID = instanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getId();
```

I am unable to find the error. Can anyone help me regarding this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in /data/app/com.notnul.notnul-1/base.apk)
            at com.notnul.notnul.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:53)
 this is my logcat @ Yashir Tahir

Comment: Did you try clean build?

Comment: For additional inputs you can check the gradle dependecies tree by typing `gradle -q app:dependencies --configuration compile` then update the dependencies in `build.gradle` like: `compile('com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1') {
exclude module: 'support-v4';
}
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'`. You can check [Diego Giorgini's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37356831/5995040) or [stegranet's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37355739/5995040) implementation. Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

Update to Google Play services library version 9.0.2.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases says:

> Google Play services updated to 9.0.1
>
> The Google Play services version 9.0.1 release is now available. This release fixes the following issues with the version 9.0.0 release:
>
> Fixes a class change compilation error with ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir().

Comment: if( !sharedPreferences.getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER,false)) {
                instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
                try {
                    GCM_Token = instanceID.getToken(authorizedEntity,
                            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                GCM_InstaceID = instanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getId();
                sendRegistrationToServer(GCM_Token);
            }help me for this

Comment: @KishanSingh If you have a solution, post it as a properly formatted answer. Thanks.