# How to fix this issue FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[IntentService]: app is crashes and getting java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

Working on google `GCM` related and Push `Notification` from last 2 months App is not crashing.from yesterday on wards app is crashing.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    try {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this); // crashes here


        registrationId = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);            


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

**Dependencies**

> compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
>      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
>      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'

**Log**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[IntentService]: app is crashes and
>   getting java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38817093/7320259 try this

Comment: I think check the com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm version, did you update version?

Comment: Try the suggested solution in this [thread](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin/issues/182) by adding configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    }
}

Comment: Last month Android studio updated due that I m facing this issue

Comment: after adding some library in my project,  getting same error "java.lang.inCompatibleClassChangeError".